# Java: Extend class as array

Tags: java, arrays, extends

Quick novice question: I want to extend a class as an array, like so

```
public class Map extends Item[][]
{

}
```

Is this possible, am I going about it the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: I guess in your case could be better Composition, instead of Inheritance...

Comment: I would take a look at the Collections API as there may already be the type of class you are looking for. Also, this would allow you to correctly use interfaces in your code (e.g. `Map`). If not then favour composition over inheritance and have your class have a property that is the internal array storage.

Comment: What purpose could extending it as an "array" serve that extending it regularly from `Item` doesn't?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arrays are weird beasts.  The have some properties, like `length` but they are not a class, so you can't extend them like you are attempting.

I think you are better off using composition, i.e. create a class that contains an `Item[][]`
and then extend that class (if you need to, having one class might be enough)

Comment: Alternatively you can extend List, e.g. ArrayList. But composition is definitely better.

Comment: @AlexR yes, if he really wants a collection.  I'm assuming he wants an array.  I try to avoid automatically thinking "use a collection" whenever I see an array.

Comment: I have a similar question: if class '''Map extends Item[]''' is not allowed why is '''List<? extends Item[]>''' allowed and what is the type of this list? @hvgotcodes