# Why Java does not allow to extend array type

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, syntax

As an experiment, I tried to extend an `int`-array like this:

```
public class IntArrayExtension extends int[]{
 // additional fields and methods.
}
```

to add some methods related to sorting, swapping, sub-array building etc. in the class itself. But I got this error while compiling:

```
IntArrayExtension.java:1: unexpected type
found   : int[]
required: class
public class IntArrayExtension extends int[]{
                                          ^
1 error
```

I am curious to know: why Java does not allow to extend an array?

Comment: Might be a better question for Programmers SE. Also see my question [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/239194/87528).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Extend class as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914928/java-extend-class-as-array)

Comment: because it's a primitive not a class. You could extend from ArrayList instead but you will be having List

Comment: @Eran I don't think so, as that question asks: whether java allows so. Whereas my question is: why Java does not allow this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Extending a fundamental type such as a `String` or an array opens up security holes. If Java let you extend an array, its methods that take arrays would become insecure. That is why strings are `final`, and arrays cannot be extended at all.

For example, you could override the `clone()` method, and return an array of incorrect size. This has a potential of breaking the logic of system code that takes an array as its parameter.

On top of that, arrays are special objects in Java, in that they do not have a class definition.

There are two solution to the problem that you are trying to solve:

- You could put the logic into a helper class with static methods, similar to `Collections`, etc. or
- You could encapsulate an array inside your `IntArrayExtension` class, and provide wrapper methods for accessing the array and its additional features.

Comment: I think the argument that it would allow someone to override the `clone()` method might be invalid.  If a method of a superclass is declared as final, then it cannot be overidden in a derived class.

Comment: I get why he wants to do this.  I'd like to do the same to add Linq-style code into Java.  It is inconvenient that you can't declare an array `Thing[] list = new Thing[100];`,  access elements using array syntax 'Thing thisThing = list[50];` and also use extension methods: 'Thing[] subset = list.Where( new Comparator<Thing>,,, ).  And you can't override the [] operator to simplify code either.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are objects but an array type is not a class and therefore can't be extended. See for example [JLS #10.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8).

Answer (score 0):

Instances of int[] are instances of java.lang.Object but the int[] type is not a class (unlike any other instance of java.lang.Object), so there's no class to extend. It's one of those interesting design quirks of Java.

But even if it were possible to extend int[] as if it were a class, it might not be the best approach to achieve the things you want anyway:

- It's not very generic as it can then only sort/swap/copy/etc int[] arrays; not arrays of any other type such as double[]. Is such a self-imposed limitation necessary?
- All the functionality that you want from arrays is available in java.util.Arrays anyway, which can handle any array type (int[], double[], MyAwesomeType<?>[], whatever).
- Extending classes to merely just bolt on more functionality on top is generally to be avoided IMHO: Now other already existing (in this case) int[] arrays need to become instances of your new class to be able to access your awesome new functionality, and there's usually no need for this (and in this case there's definitely no need for this).