# Is there a way to restrict generic parameters to be arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, restriction

I tried "T extends Array" but that doesnt work,

```
public class Foo<T extends Array> {
    { ...}
}

public class Bar {
    {
        Foo<int[]> f; <-- Error
    }
}
```

From what I saw, I dont think its posible, but hey, I'm not a Java guru

Comment: No, but you can simply only ever use `T` in an array-like way, e.g. returning `T[]`, accepting `T[]` parameters etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner But that wouldn't support arrays of primitives (`int[]`) the question example uses, only arrays of objects.

Comment: @Andreas it would not; but there are more types it does work for than the 8 it doesn't.

Comment: @AndyTurner The funny thing is, i needed it for primitive types.
Well, i saw it coming, Thanks!

Comment: How would it be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't extend a class with `Array`. You can only extend Java types like classes, interfaces etc. (You can also not extend `int` since it is a primitive type). If you want a new type of array you have to create an array of that object e.g. `int[] intArray = new int[5];` or `Foo[] foo = new Foo[5];`

[read here for why it is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913612/why-java-does-not-allow-to-extend-array-type)

Comment: I didnt meant to extend array, i just wanted to know if there was a wild card for restricting parameters, mainly to use shared things like .length and such.
I can use a wayaround for objects but not primitive types, but luckily I just had to repeat code 8 times, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict the type variable `T` to array-of-references types, you can instead have `T` be the component type, and restrict the component type, and use `T[]` where you need the array type, i.e. instead of

```
public class Foo<T extends Object[]> {
   T obj;
}

Foo<String[]> f;
```

you would have

```
public class Foo<T extends Object> {
   T[] obj;
}

Foo<String> f;
```

If you want to allow `T` to be array-of-primitives types too, that's not possible without allowing non-array reference types too, because the only supertype of array-of-primitive types like `int[]`, `boolean[]`, etc. is `Object` (and perhaps also `Cloneable` and `Serializable`). There is no supertype of "just" primitive and reference arrays. The most restrictive you can do would be something like

```
public class Foo<T extends Cloneable & Serializable>
```

and if you did that, you would not be able to do anything with `T` except the things that you can do to any `Object` anyway (note that neither the `Cloneable` nor `Serializable` interfaces provide any methods), so then you might as well not restrict `T` at all.